# use special characters in strings.xml to load in WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-view

I am using `WebView` to display the String resource. Here is the code-

```
<string name="abc">à</string>
<string name="abcd">è</string>
```

When i load this in my `webView` it displays some garbage values. How to display this special characters in a `WebView`??

Comment: you have to tell your webview you are using utf-8

Comment: @njzk2 - ya.i have done it. here is the code -webView.loadData(details[mIndex], "text/html", "UTF-8");

Comment: what is details[mIndex] ?

Comment: @njzk2 - details[mIndex]=getResources().getString(R.string.abc);

Comment: what happens if you display this text in a textview ?

Answer (score 4):

Check [this](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php) list of special characters and how to encode in html.

```
<string name="abc">&#224;</string>
<string name="abc">&#232;</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enter these values into your values `XML` file using the *graphical interface*, the IDE will automatically format them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Put symbol code in string tag:

```
<string name="welcome">Welcome &#33;</string>
```

Output will be look like:
                         Welcome !

For more symbol code use below link :

http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

Enjoy...

Comment: characters in the link you have provided are not working on android string xml